# How to all iphone and ipad simulator to image center screen?

Tags: ios, image

I have created new app for iOS. The first initial page image has been added. I have checked the simulator with a different view. How should I the  center of the screen shows the image, textbox and button? Please help me.

Comment: Either you have to use auto layout or auto resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to add constraints? What you need to do is set constraint to center screen horizontally and text box center vertical. After that apply top and bottom constraint to image and button.

You can follow http://www.raywenderlich.com/115444/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2-constraints to lear more about constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it by giving just simply two constraint with giving height and width

Horizontal center in container and vertical center in container